# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'backprop'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of CrossEntropy loss. Below is the code section. And I am getting the following error. What would be the reason?

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'backprop'

Could you please help me? Thanks so much !

```
class CrossEntropyLoss:
  def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the loss module."""
    self.pred = None

  def __call__(self, pred, target):
    """This is needed to be able to use the object like a function. The task
      is handled by the forward function. 
      
      pred: A module object (layer or non-linearity)
      target: Numpy array storing the correct/target values.
    """
    return self.forward(pred, target)
```

**I calculated CrossEntroy loss.**

```
  def forward(self, pred, target):
    """Feedforward processing through the loss.
      
      pred: A module object (layer or non-linearity). Assumed to be scores.
      target: Numpy array storing the correct/target values.
      Returns: The scalar loss value.
    """
    self.pred = pred # save input object for later use
    self.target = target # save target for later use
    self.scores = pred.out # get the scores from the input object
    self.N = self.scores.shape[0] 

    self.probs = None # Save calculated probabilities into this
    loss = None # Save calculated loss into this
    ###########################################################################
    # @TODO: (i) Convert scores to probabilities and save it in self.probs    #
    #        (ii) Calculate Cross-entropy loss. Note that this will be a      #
    #             scalar.                                                     #
    #   Don't add weight regularization here. We implement it directly as     #
    #   weight decay. Don't forget to normalize the loss.                     #
    ###########################################################################   
    self.target=self.scores.shape[0]
    self.pred=self.scores 
    self.probs=np.exp(self.pred)/np.sum(np.exp(self.pred))    
    log=-np.log(self.probs)
    loss=np.sum(np.dot(self.target,log))
    loss+=(self.target-self.pred)/self.N
    pass
    ##########################################################################
    #                       END OF YOUR CODE                                 #
    ##########################################################################
   
    return loss
```

**I want to calculate dervative of loss but I am getting an error in self.pred.backprop(self.dscores) **

```
def backprop(self):
"""Start backpropagate with this loss definition. Calculate the derivative
   wrt. the scores and pass that to the earlier module 
   via self.inp.backprop(self.dscores).
"""
self.dscores = None # Calculate and save the derivative wrt the scores here
###########################################################################
# @TODO: Calculate self.dscores. Don't forget to normalize the gradient.  #
###########################################################################
self.dscores=self.pred-1
self.dscores/=self.N    
pass
##########################################################################
#                       END OF YOUR CODE                                 #
##########################################################################
self.pred.backprop(self.dscores)
```

**Error**

> ```
> > >     
> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> > last) <ipython-input-270-9c36ff3edc52> in <module>()
> >      39 preds = model(X_val)
> >      40 loss_fn(preds, y_val)
> > ---> 41 loss_fn.backprop()
> >      42 grad_numerical = grad_check_sparse(f, x=model.fc1.W, analytic_grad=model.fc1.dW, num_checks=10)
> >      43 
> > 
> > <ipython-input-269-559ef6f7f0c9> in backprop(self)
> >      62     #                       END OF YOUR CODE                                 #
> >      63     ##########################################################################
> > ---> 64     self.pred.backprop(self.dscores)
> >      65 
> >      66   def update(self, learning_rate):
> > 
> > AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'backprop'
> ```

Comment: Isn't it obvious?  `self.pred` is a numpy array.  What class has `backprop` as a method?

Comment: I see `pred` argument in several places, but I don't see where it is defined/created.

Comment: I'am a new so I don't understand yours comments. Can you specify where I should make changes? This is a neural network. I have three classes. Linear Layer, ReLU and CrossEntroyLoss.

Comment: It's hard to know what's your code - that you wrote and understand, and what you've copied from other sources.  If you don't know Python, then it is hard to help.